# df.drop in a for loop taking too long

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having issues with my code taking too long to run, and am unsure about how to make it more efficient/ run faster.

I have a data frame of about 3.5 million observations and have this code as my criteria within the for loop. If I drop the  trades = trades.drop([i], axis=0) section then it takes seconds and doesn't drop the rows, however, with this line of code it hasn't even stopped running yet.

Ideally I would allocate all of the rows where the for loop is successful into another data frame as I know what to do from there, but I am unsure about how to do that which is why the .drop is there.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
# Drop the rows/ trades that are greater than the ASK_PLUS_SPREAD
counter = 0
for i in range(0, len(trades['ASK_PLUS_SPREAD'])):
    if trades['PRICE'][i] > trades['ASK_PLUS_SPREAD'][i]:
        counter = counter + 1
        counts_q['F5'] = counter
        trades = trades.drop([i], axis=0)
    else:
        pass
    
# Drop the rows/ trades that are lower than the BID_MINUS_SPREAD and add the amount taken to the counter
for i in range(0, len(trades['BID_MINUS_SPREAD'])):
    if trades['PRICE'][i] < trades['BID_MINUS_SPREAD'][i]:
        counter = counter + 1
        counts_q['F5'] = counter 
        trades = trades.drop([i], axis = 0)
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the trades df with only rows where `PRICE` is greater than `ASK_PLUS_SPREAD`.

```
trades = trades[trades['PRICE'] > trades['ASK_PLUS_SPREAD]]
```

If you want some sort of comparison of how many rows were removed, I'd look into comparing `trades.shape` before and after the change.

Answer (score 0):

What you did in the line

```
 trades = trades.drop([i], axis=0)
```

is to create a new DataFrame by dropping one row from the old DataFrame. That' s why it is slow. You can parallelize your operation by using Boolean indexing. Consider

```
trades['PRICE'] > trades['ASK_PLUS_SPREAD']
```

this takes the column `PRICE` and column `ASK_PLUS_SPREAD` as two series and compare, which the result is a new series, in Boolean.

Now you can do two things with it: Firstly,

```
count = (trades['PRICE'] > trades['ASK_PLUS_SPREAD']).sum()
```

which counts how many `PRICE` greater than `ASK_PLUS_SPREAD` (since True is regarded as 1 and False is 0 in this case). Secondly,

```
trades = trades[trades['PRICE'] > trades['ASK_PLUS_SPREAD']]
```

which selects only the rows that fits the condition. In fact, if you don't need to count which is less and which is greater, you can replace the entire code in your example with the following:

```
condition = (trades['PRICE'] > trades['ASK_PLUS_SPREAD']) | (trades['PRICE'] < trades['BID_MINUS_SPREAD'])
counter = condition.sum()
trades = trades[condition]
```

which `|` is a bitwise OR. You need to use bitwise operation to combine boolean series.

Comment: That worked great, and I have created another data frame in which the values exist that are > ASK_PLUS_SPREAD - `trades_out3 = trades[trades['PRICE'] > trades['ASK_PLUS_SPREAD']]`.  I need to delete these values from the original data frame. However, the code I am using is not working `trades = trades[~trades_out3].reset_index(drop=True)` and comes up with error: TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'DatetimeArray'

Comment: `trades_out3` seems to be a dataframe to me, not a series. You can't use that for Boolean indexing. Are you looking for `trades[~(trades['PRICE']>trades['ASK_PLUS_SPREAD'])].reset_index(drop=True)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help, everything is sorted now.